# Question related to differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I do not know the eg I am using can be on the site before.
Actually, I was learning differential operators using a book given by our prof , and there was an example in it says like this>
$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}-3\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=e^{5x}$ now I have solved these kinds of question using the characteristic equation but how do I solve it using inverse operation of differential. And how these two methods are physically different in general using characteristic equation two roots will $y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$
but how do I solve it using the inverse operator, please can anybody share me the process of solving it. There is no proper site or papers to learn it so I will be very much happy if anyone can do an analysis for this question.

edit:I have posted the same question in chat room for an answer,and my problems were critically understood by user @semiclassical and what he says is
Notationally you’d write your ODE as $(D^2−3D+2)y(x)=e^{5x}$, with $D=d/dx$.
Or w/e your prof uses for differentiation
One then can factor the left side as $(D−1)(D−2)y$, which makes evident that the characteristic polynomial has roots 1,2
The less-obvious part is how to get the particular solution
The simplest way is to guess it (method of undetermined coefficients)
Formally one does have $y=(D−1)−1(D−2)−1e^{5x}$ but figuring out how to apply that is the problem?
this what I want to understand and how can I generalize it for the equation which has
**n roots (all are different)**
**n roots(all are same)**
**n roots(some are imaginary)**

Comment: This operator inversion is essentially the same as the method of undetermined coefficients, and has the same limitations on the right side. One could say that the operator calculus is a more systematic version.

Comment: @LutzLehmann can write a answer on your point

Comment: @LutzLehmann especially the edit part one,

Comment: Essentially, $p(D)y=ce^{ax}$ gets transformed to $y=p(a+(D-a))^{-1}ce^{ax}$ and then apply formally the geometric series on the Taylor expansion of the operator, and use that $(D-a)e^{ax}=0$ to find $y(x)=\frac{c}{p(a)}e^{ax}$ as a particular solution. The case $p(a)=0$ needs of course extra treatment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}-3\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=e^{5x}$$
$$(D^2-3D+2)y=e^{5x}$$
$$(D-1)(D-2)y=e^{5x}$$
$$y=\dfrac 1 {(D-1)(D-2)}e^{5x}$$
By fraction decomposition:
$$y=\dfrac 1{(D-2)}{e^{5x}}-\dfrac 1{(D-1)}{e^{5x}}$$
Now I use the well known result:
$$\dfrac  1{D-a}e^b=e^b\dfrac 1 {D+b-a}1$$
$$y=\dfrac 1{(D-2)}{e^{5x}}-\dfrac 1{(D-1)}{e^{5x}}$$
$$y=\dfrac 1{(D-2)}{e^{2x}e^{3x}}-\dfrac 1{(D-1)}{e^{4x}e^x}$$
$$y=e^{2x}\dfrac 1{D}{e^{3x}}-e^x\dfrac 1{D}{e^{4x}}$$
Integrate the exponentials:
$$y=e^{2x}(\dfrac {e^{3x}}3+A)-e^x(\dfrac {e^{4x}}4+B)$$
Finally:
$$y(x)=C_1e^x+C_2e^{2x}+\dfrac {e^{5x}}{12}$$
This lead to the same result you get with classical methods.

Comment: I am lost on fourth line can u please edit and write how u reached at 4

Comment: I will add some steps @JackRod

Comment: Is this more clear @JackRod .?

Comment: yes, it is, I have one request can u give me just 10 min of u  in chat I have some confusion related to this concept?

Comment: I am at work but if you have questions you can ask here If I know the answer I will help @JackRod

Comment: where math.stackexchange user come chat for math discussions @mtglasser I would not take your much time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129628/discussion-between-jack-rod-and-mtglasser).